# Apache Commons Options main parameter

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons

Is it possible to retrieve the "command line" parameters using Apache Commons? 
I'm trying to retrieve the parameters of, for example:

./test -d 5 file.txt

I'd like to retrieve `file.txt` parameter, but I didn't find an Apache Commons class for that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Command-line arguments are passed to your `main` method.

Comment: I recommend to use [`args4j`](https://github.com/kohsuke/args4j) which has a much nicer API.